# Excel lagging when entering equations into textbox

Tags: excel, excel-formula, finance, lag

Context: This is a financial model, which I recently converted from Excel 97-2003 workbook to the modern version (.xlsx)

Excel experiences a 4-5 seconds lag in my financial model spreadsheet when entering equations into textbox. It's driving me crazy.

I have done 4 things till now but none work:

1. Went to options > advanced > and disabled automatically flash fill
2. Set my calculation options to manual since I have a lot of formulas
3. Went to task manager > set Excel to high priority
4. Went to options > advanced  > and disabled hardware acceleration

Could anyone please give some directions, starting point or solution?

Comment: How big is this spreadsheet? How much memory do you have? If you are down on 4 gig then...

Comment: What does the textbox do? Is something referencing that or is it triggering a macro?

Comment: @Solar Mike The spreadsheet is pretty small (623 KB).

Comment: @P.b The textbox just has equations. No macros. No references. No fancy stuff.